# Text 'stretched' in a table

Tags: tables

I have a minor problem, although I'm unsure how to fix it. The two tables below show the tables as they appear in my thesis:

[image]

As you can see the space between the words 'Each' and 'successive' is too much. However when I try to replicate the problem with a MWE, the problem does **not** appear:

[image]

What could be causing the stretched words? I have other packages loaded in my main thesis document, but I don't think they are relevant to this problem.

My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Course Load of a Representative EBE student}
\label{table:eng}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.20\textwidth}*{3}{L{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Cumulative Number of Prescribed Credits}
\\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
& BSc (Eng)& ASPECT & BSc (Geomatics) \\
\midrule
First-year & \multicolumn{1}{c}{144 -- 148} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{104 -- 116} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{142 -- 144} \\
Each successive \hbox{two-year} period\tnote{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{264 -- 294} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{232 -- 248} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{296 -- 330} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `\usepackage[english]{babel}\usepackage{microtype}`! Sometimes, this is already enough to get it better looking. In order to help, you will have to reproduce your error. Your MWE looks allright.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The three first columns are set justified, and there is no hyphenation. You will find the same stretching if you change the type size to `\small` in your MWE. So probably you have a smaller point size for the tables in your document than in the MWE.

Change the first (or the three first) column(s) to ragged right by using the new column type `L` that you have defined, *i.e.* :

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}L{0.20\textwidth}*{3}{L{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}@{}}
```

instead of

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.20\textwidth}*{3}{L{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}@{}}
```

In my opinion, ragged right is better for this type of tables. Only if you  have a column with lot of text, you may consider to set it justified, but then you often have to enforce manual hyphenation. And of course LaRiFaRi recommendation of using `microtype`is good, but will not solve this particular problem.

In your definition of the centred column, you have used `\Centering`with capital `C`, change that to `\centering`. If you change the last column to a `C` column, the column names in the last three columns line up nicely. Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % < - changed
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{threeparttable}
\small                     % < - to demonstrate stratching if justified first column
\caption{Course Load of a Representative EBE student}
\label{table:eng}
\begin{tabular}{@{}L{0.20\textwidth}*{3}{C{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}@{}}
% Change the column type to L and C
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries Cumulative Number of Prescribed Credits}
\\
\cmidrule(l){2-4}
& BSc (Eng)& ASPECT & BSc (Geomatics) \\
\midrule
First-year & \multicolumn{1}{c}{144 -- 148} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{104 -- 116} &       \multicolumn{1}{c}{142 -- 144} \\
Each successive \hbox{two-year} period\tnote{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{264 -- 294} &    \multicolumn{1}{c}{232 -- 248} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{296 -- 330} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE-example]